# heroku django server error

Tags: python, django, heroku

Trying to deploy django project on heroku:
https://crmtestnewone.herokuapp.com/crm/

Do all as this instruction said but getting error (Server Error (500))
https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial-extensions/blob/master/heroku/README.md

```
2016-10-06T14:01:38.045036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/crm/" host=crmtestnewone.herokuapp.com request_id=4981504b-0314-48ee-8a1b-ef7c51062b8f fwd="95.108.174.232" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=500 bytes=253
```

I only can enter /admin page

```
2016-10-06T14:03:37.432783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=crmtestnewone.herokuapp.com request_id=854e9324-a660-4a4e-ac19-8a9e693331c2 fwd="95.108.174.232" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=85ms status=200 bytes=4891
2016-10-06T14:03:37.596058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" host=crmtestnewone.herokuapp.com request_id=65fcb7df-bbe8-4731-aabc-24c1886c7300 fwd="95.108.174.232" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=304
2016-10-06T14:03:37.597996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/base.css" host=crmtestnewone.herokuapp.com request_id=2ed877bd-c9f7-4b3d-b613-c479d75d1ef1 fwd="95.108.174.232" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=299
```

Can you give any advice to me? Why admin page working (i can create objects in my models), but look like pure html without any style and my other pages dont work at all?

UPDATE:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'crm',
'bootstrapform',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dive_into.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dive_into.wsgi.application'

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/crm/'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==1.10.1
django-bootstrap-form==3.2.1
gunicorn==19.4.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
dj-database-url==0.4.0
```

Comment: Can you post your settings.py file and requirements,txt?

Comment: udpate question

Comment: Could you try setting `Debug` to `True` in the settings file and then checking the error that is thrown by the url? We can then work from there. As for the static files, that happens because Django doesn't serve static files in production and you'll require to configure some things

Answer (score 0):

change to debug=true, got error:
Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '=' in
problem was in:
    {% if search_clients = 'no auth'%}
it should be ==
It works fine localy throught.

Newtt thanks for your help!